# Failed to access script-runner.jar in Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a EMR cluster (version 7.0) in the region us-west-2. I tried to run a script as a step by

```bash
aws emr add-steps \
 --cluster-id j-1JLC9879Cxxxx \
 --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="Do Something",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[s3://my-bucket/my_script.sh]
```

Note "script-runner.jar" is also in the region us-west-2.

However, it failed with "controller" log

[image]

```bash
2024-01-03T18:56:08.771Z INFO Ensure step 3 jar file s3://us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
INFO Failed to download: s3://us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error whilst fetching 's3://us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar'
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchS3HadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:500)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchHadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:439)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.stepsv2.HadoopJarStepRunner$Runner.<init>(HadoopJarStepRunner.java:275)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.stepsv2.HadoopJarStepRunner.createRunner(HadoopJarStepRunner.java:184)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.stepsv2.StepsExecutor.runStep(StepsExecutor.java:222)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.stepsv2.StepsExecutor.processNextStepFromDb(StepsExecutor.java:112)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.stepsv2.StepsExecutor.run(StepsExecutor.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: VGNFV105RGV9K7EE; S3 Extended Request ID: 5irEguAoUr+mqEk8962irdy0octqupzn3PFfbC2gvopkXLSuxJvkbegOwPaQzp2JDgYnR8ErFPBKyVWNigdlpQ==; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 5irEguAoUr+mqEk8962irdy0octqupzn3PFfbC2gvopkXLSuxJvkbegOwPaQzp2JDgYnR8ErFPBKyVWNigdlpQ==
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5520)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5467)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1554)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1408)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.copyS3ObjectToFile(S3Wrapper.java:391)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.getFileWithS3Endpoint(S3Wrapper.java:344)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.getFile(S3Wrapper.java:377)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchS3HadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:487)
    ... 13 more
```

It seems EMR cluster cannot access `s3://us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar`.

So I tried to add below permission for the service role of this EMR cluster, but still got same error.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::us-west-2.elasticmapreduce"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::us-west-2.elasticmapreduce/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!